# How to set up ASP.NET Core 6 Web API CORS for React app?

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, cors, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to set up an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API that can be called from a React application using fetch API calls. I have been following Microsoft's documentation ([Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0)) and have only partially had success.

I can successfully call a GET. I can successfully call a POST only if the values are passed a query string. If I try and POST with a body I get an error.

Example GET in React from `http://localhost:3000/`:

```
await fetch('http://localhost:14157/Test', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include',
});
```

Example POST in React to `http://localhost:3000/`

```
await fetch('http://localhost:14157/Test', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
    }),
});
```

ASP.NET Core 6 Web API `Program.cs`:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                policy =>
                                {
                                    policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                                    .AllowCredentials();
                                });
        });

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }
}
```

TestController

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post(User user)
    {
        return Ok(user);
    }
}
```

I end up never hitting the breakpoint inside my Post method in my controller and get this error in Chrome Dev Tools:

> Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:14157/Test' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

My React application is running on `http://localhost:3000/` and my ASP.NET Core Web API is running on `http://localhost:14157/`.

Is there any configuration I am missing?

**Update:** I pushed my examples to public BitBucket repositories if you have time to take a look. [.NET Web API](https://bitbucket.org/stackoverflow-user12858805/corsapi/src/master/) and [React](https://bitbucket.org/stackoverflow-user12858805/corsreact/src/master/). Thank you!

Comment: With endpoint routing, the CORS middleware must be configured to execute between the calls to UseRouting and UseEndpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on. But I use the exact same code and it worked. I'm wondering if you have some other code not listed.

Your CORS configuration has no problem.

------------ Edit -----------
Hi @user12858805,

I downloaded your code from Bitbucket and it still works fine. Below is the screenshot.

[image]

The only thing I changed is `corsapi/Properties/launchSettings.json`, when start using kestrel the url was not http://localhost:14157. I started the API using `dotnet run`.

[image]

Are you using IIS?

Comment: I pushed my examples to public BitBucket repositories if you have time to take a look. [.NET Web API](https://bitbucket.org/stackoverflow-user12858805/corsapi/src/master/) and [React](https://bitbucket.org/stackoverflow-user12858805/corsreact/src/master/). Thank you!

Comment: @user12858805 I tried your code and it still worked fine. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your react js file you have to use cors mode within the request options used during the invocation of fetch (see last property "mode" within the request options):

```
await fetch('http://localhost:14157/Test', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
    }),
    mode: "cors"
});
```